# Xpath Query: attribute with "array" as value

Tags: php, xpath

Let's say that I have a html `input` tag with an attribute like this

```
data-field-info='{"value":"2","date":"2014-01-08"}'
```

How can I use `XPath` and his `query` method to retrieve only tha tag with a certain date?

I know that I can do this with an expression like

```
//input[@data-field-info='2014-01-08']
```

but this would works only if `data-field-info` has a "scalar" value

Can someone point me in the right direction? I've no idea

Comment: You might need to get *all* the elements, parse the JSON, then find the correct ones.

Comment: Or maybe something like: `//input[contains(@data-field-info,'2014-01-08')]`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Json way is what came first in my mind, but I was wondering about something compact an "faster" (at least to write). I've never read about the second option you gave me, I'll give it a try! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the `contains()` function to see if the attribute contains the date.

```
//input[contains(@data-field-info,'2014-01-08')]
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/87213

DOCS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPath/Functions/contains

Comment: Yeah ... or if you need to be more precise, `//input[contains(@data-field-info,'"date":"2014-01-08"')]`.